# Using relative path in Python3 generic code

Tags: python-3.x, path, directory

I have a question about code in python. If I have the following directory structure:

```
+code
    -main.py
+data
    -somedata.csv
```

I can run?

```
python3 code/main.py --data="data/somedata.csv"
```

Actually I'm using absolute path to my data, I like to make the program more generic.

Comment: To me the path's look relative... relative to the current directory you're executing that command in. Absolute path would be something like `/home/user/yourName/programming/proj1/code/main.py` Please elaborate what you mean by "making the program more generic"

Comment: Whether that command line does what you want depends entirely on what `main.py` does and how it is implemented.